# Flatten CALayer sublayers into one layer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, core-graphics

In my app I have one root layer, and many images which are sublayers of rootLayer. I'd like to flatten all the sublayers of rootLayer into one layer/image, that don't have any sublayers. I think I should do this by drawing all sublayers in core graphics context, but I don't know how to do that.

I hope you'll understand me, and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your own example for Mac OS X:

```
CGContextRef myBitmapContext = MyCreateBitmapContext(800,600);
[rootLayer renderInContext:myBitmapContext];
CGImageRef myImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(myBitmapContext);
rootLayer.contents = (id) myImage;
rootLayer.sublayers = nil;
CGImageRelease(myImage);
```

iOS:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rootLayer.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[rootLayer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *layerImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
rootLayer.contents = (id) layerImage.CGImage;
rootLayer.sublayers = nil;
```

Also note the caveat in the docs:

> The Mac OS X v10.5 implementation of
>   this method does not support the
>   entire Core Animation composition
>   model. QCCompositionLayer,
>   CAOpenGLLayer, and QTMovieLayer layers
>   are not rendered. Additionally, layers
>   that use 3D transforms are not
>   rendered, nor are layers that specify
>   backgroundFilters, filters,
>   compositingFilter, or a mask values.

Comment: Thank you! Although it's shame that's filters, and 3d transforms are not supported.

Comment: Doesn’t work; the image returned is blank (all-white).

Answer (score 1):

Do you still want the layer to be interactive? If not, call `-renderInContext:` and show the bitmap context.

Comment: as I said I don't know how to do this.

I wrote: http://en.pastebin.ca/1744529

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I also once considered using `render(in: CGContext)`.
However, I decided not to after reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410909-render):

> **Important**
>
> The OS X v10.5 implementation of this method does not support the entire Core Animation composition model. QCCompositionLayer, CAOpenGLLayer, and QTMovieLayer layers are not rendered. Additionally, layers that use 3D transforms are not rendered, nor are layers that specify **backgroundFilters**, **filters**, **compositingFilter**, or a **mask** values. Future versions of macOS may add support for rendering these layers and properties.

*Seriously, no masks? I say, "WORK, Apple."*

For a caveat, it's too huge to ignore, so I had to find a different approach.

## solution

```swift
extension CALayer {
    func flatten(in size: CGSize) -> CALayer {
        let flattenedLayer = CALayer(in: size)
        flattenedLayer.contents = getCGImage(in: size)
        return flattenedLayer
    }
}
```

It converts `CALayer` into `CGImage` and make a new `CALayer` with flattened image as its contents.
Of course, I had to make `getCGImage(in: CGSize)` as well, using `CARenderer`.

## implementation

```swift
import AppKit
import Metal

let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
let context = CIContext()
var textureDescriptor: MTLTextureDescriptor = {
    let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: .rgba8Unorm, width: 0, height: 0, mipmapped: false)
    textureDescriptor.usage = [MTLTextureUsage.shaderRead, .shaderWrite, .renderTarget]
    return textureDescriptor
}()

let maxScaleFactor = NSScreen.screens.reduce(1) { max($0, $1.backingScaleFactor) }
let scaleTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(maxScaleFactor, maxScaleFactor, 1)
let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!

extension CALayer {
    convenience init(in size: CGSize, with sublayer: CALayer? = nil) {
        self.init()
        frame.size = size
        if let sublayer { addSublayer(sublayer) }
    }

    func getCGImage(in size: CGSize) -> CGImage {
        let ciImage = getCIImage(in: size)
        return context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)!
    }
    
    func getCIImage(in size: CGSize) -> CIImage {
        let superlayer = self.superlayer
        let ciImage = CALayer(in: size, with: self).ciImage
        if let superlayer { superlayer.addSublayer(self) }
        return ciImage
    }
    
    var ciImage: CIImage {
        let width = frame.size.width * maxScaleFactor
        let height = frame.size.height * maxScaleFactor
        textureDescriptor.width = Int(width)
        textureDescriptor.height = Int(height)
        let texture: MTLTexture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor)!
        let renderer = CARenderer(mtlTexture: texture)
        
        transform = scaleTransform
        frame = .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: width, height: height))
        renderer.bounds = frame
        renderer.layer = self
        
        CATransaction.flush()
        CATransaction.commit()
        
        renderer.beginFrame(atTime: 0, timeStamp: nil)
        renderer.render()
        renderer.endFrame()
        
        return CIImage(mtlTexture: texture, options: [.colorSpace: colorSpace])!
    }
}
```

There are a few things to note:

- use of `CATransform3D` to match resolution of HiDPI display
- temporarily added as a new `CALayer`'s sublayer in `getCIImage(in: CGSize)` for layers like `CAShapeLayer` with zero frame size; this is also to get the image independent from its frame origin/position
- use of `CATransaction.flush()` [to transfer ownership of the layer tree to the `CARenderer`’s context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73653035)

## extras

Since [`CALayer` can have `NSImage` as its contents too in macOS 10.6 and later](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410773-contents), you can change the function accordingly.

```swift
extension CALayer {
    func getNSImage(in size: CGSize) -> NSImage {
        let ciImage = getCIImage(in: size)
        return NSImage(data: ciImage.pngData)!
    }
}

extension CIImage {
    var pngData: Data { context.pngRepresentation(of: self, format: .RGBA8, colorSpace: colorSpace!)! }
    // jpeg, tiff, etc. can be created the same way
}
```

Coming this far, saving as image is not hard at all,
but using `write...Representation(of: CIImage, ...)` is probably the easiest way:

```swift
extension CALayer {
    func saveAsPNG(at url: URL, in size: CGSize? = nil) {
        let image = size == nil ? ciImage : getCIImage(in: size!)
        return try! context.writePNGRepresentation(of: image, to: url, format: .RGBA8, colorSpace: colorSpace)
    }
    // jpeg, tiff, etc. can be saved the same way
}
```