# How do I flatten CALayers

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, layer

I am rewriting an app that was using the core graphics library because it is extremely slow in iOS 4 and above. I am converting a lot of the code using the Core Animation library instead (specifically CALayer). The way I am doing it involves adding sublayers to a root layer. The problem is that it is a drawing program so it ends up with a lot of sublayers very quickly, and after about 20 it starts losing a lot of performance. I am trying to find a way to merge sublayers into one another or merge the sublayers into some background image. It would also be ideal if your suggestions minimized the use of the Core Graphics library (unless their performance wasn't impacted in iOS 4 and above). Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Core Graphics is *not* slow.  In fact, it's very easy to misuse/abuse Core Animation in such a way that it becomes slow.  What does Instruments tell you about what in Core Graphics was slow?

Comment: I haven't used any instruments, but the app I am working on is fine on iOS 3, but iOS 4 and above it becomes far too slow to work. The reason why I am pointing fingers at CG is because of blogs posts I read like this one: http://blog.mundue.net/2010/06/ios4-why-you-so-slow/

Comment: Yes, Core Graphic will be extrem SLOW if you are trying to call draw st multiple of times(especially CGContextDrawImage) because every time you execute this method it will call (void)drawRect. Should avoid this, use CALayer is a right choice in this case.

Comment: This might answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034674/flatten-calayer-sublayers-into-one-layer