# Having many small CATextLayers make resizing the window slow

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa, optimization, core-animation

When I resize a window containing about 10,000 `CATextLayers`, the initial resizing freezes the window for a few seconds. After the initial freeze, resizing stutters noticeably.

Profiling and common sense suggest that this is slow because of all the internal redrawing (apparently CATextLayers use Core Text under the hood).

**What optimizations (if any) can be done to make resizing a window with 10,000 text layers fast and efficient?**

Here's the code I use to create the layers, in a simple NSView subclass:

```c
- (id) initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect]) {
        [self setLayer:[CALayer layer]];
        [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    int w = 8;
    int h = 14;

    self.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
            CATextLayer* t = [CATextLayer layer];
            t.opaque = YES;
            t.frame = NSMakeRect(x * w, y * h, w, h);
            t.foregroundColor = [NSColor blackColor].CGColor;
            t.backgroundColor = [NSColor yellowColor].CGColor;
            t.string = @"a";
            t.font = (__bridge CGFontRef)[NSFont fontWithName:@"Menlo" size:12];
            t.fontSize = 12;
            [self.layer addSublayer:t];
        }
    }
}
```

For more context: I'm creating a text grid where each cell's character, text color, and background color can be changed (kind of like Terminal.app).

For this reason, the one optimization I've thought of, which is to use a single CATextLayer per line, rather than per "cell", won't work, because a single CATextLayer can only have one foreground color and one background color.

Comment: When resizing starts, flatten 10K layers into one [by rendering them all to a bitmap layer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2034674/335858). Use the bitmap layer for resizing. Once the resizing is over, replace with 10K `CATextLayer`s again. The drawback is that the resizing in progress looks somewhat pixelated. The advantage is that it is very fast and smooth.

Comment: I did not post this as an answer because this started as a comment, and evolved into something that looks like it may be a solution as I was typing it. Anyway, I posted an answer - try it out, I am very curious to see if this helps, or if it simply shifts the CPU load to a different spot.

Comment: It sounds like you need an approach to reduce the number of layers. I can think of a way to make the whole picture with four layers - (1) a real layer with squares of foreground color in places of symbols, (2) a masking layer for #1 with the entire text rendered in alpha=1 text and alpha=0 in background, (3) a real layer with squares of background colors in places of symbols, and (4) a masking layer for #3 with the entire text rendered in alpha=0 and alpha=1 in background. Here is a [link talking about masks](http://evandavis.me/blog/2013/2/13/getting-creative-with-calayer-masks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to approach this problem as follows:

- When resizing starts, flatten 10K layers into one [by rendering them all to a bitmap layer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2034674/335858).
- Use the bitmap layer for resizing.
- Once the resizing is over, replace with 10K CATextLayers again.

The drawback is that the resizing in progress looks somewhat pixelated. In addition, rendering 10K layers onto a bitmap may be time-consuming.

The advantage is that once the rendering is complete, resizing is fast and smooth.

Comment: As a step toward that, I tried removing and re-adding the layers around a live-resize, and hiding/showing them. Both are still noticeably slow when live-resizing with about 100,000 layers.

Comment: @sdegutis 100K layers is way too much - even 10K sounded like a borderline, but 100K is a lot.

Comment: "Doc, it hurts when  I do this (put 10k or 100k layers on a view)"